# File and Filewriter

Tags: java

I need a way to delete a line, im using this to write on the file:

```
    FileWriter insert = new FileWriter(file, true);  
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(insert);  
    out.println("1. Mario");
```

I made a thing that reads line by line but i've no idea how to delete the string that returns, is that even possible?

Comment: Have two objects, one for reading and one for writing. Have a loop which will iterate over all lines and check if the line is identical to the ignored line. If not, write it to output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're reading in the lines of text write then lines you want to keep to a StringBuffer or StringBuilder then write the contents of the buffer/builder back to the file. Is there any specific reason that you're opening up the file for appending when you're wanting to remove lines of text from the file or am I missing something?

Comment: I understood your idea, thank you. The idea of the program is to simulate a database doing inserts updates and removing lines like a delete. I figured the insert and the update out but did not know how to do the delete part...